# ObjectMapper : How to get the root element in snake case

Tags: java, jackson2, jackson-databind

I am trying to read object and convert into string.  But the root element is getting changed from `payment_token` to `PaymentToken`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
String requestString = mapper.writeValueAsString(paymentToken); //paymenttoken is valid object
```

Input Object:

```
{
    "payment_token": {
        "client_id": "test",
        "currency_code": "USD" 
    }
}
```

Getting Output as:

```
{
    "PaymentToken": {
        "client_id": "test",
        "currency_code": "USD"
    }
}
```

Help me to get the root object as it is in input ?

Comment: Your JSON is broken. Also The paymentToken is unclear. Can you add how you construct paymentToken and if it has a DTO class share that also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
@JsonRootName(value = "payment_token")
public class PaymentToken {
...
}
```

Ref: [JsonRootName](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html)

If you add above annotation, Let see how it works
Add following configuration to ObjectMapper

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true); // additional to your config
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
String paymentToken = "{\"payment_token\":{\"client_id\":\"test\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}}";

System.out.println(mapper.readValue(paymentToken, PaymentToken.class));
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(paymentToken));
```

output:

> PaymentToken(clientId=test, currencyCode=USD)
>   {"String":"{\"payment_token\":{\"client_id\":\"test\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}}"}

As you can see above, objectMapper deserialize and serialize properly.

Comment: I don't have access to this class, is there any mapper configuration ?

Comment: None of the configurations is required, which Jackson version you are using? add `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.x` as dependency, version should be >= 2.4.0, I used 2.9.8 version

Comment: i am using `2.9.6` version.  not sure why it is returning root element `PaymentToken`. I can not use annotation in the pojo since i don't have the class.

Comment: you mean you do not want "PaymentToken" key in string and wanted only `{"client_id":"test","currency_code":"USD"}` ?

Comment: my ask is here as mentioned in question `Help me to get the root object as it is in input`